# DMin with Empty Column

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have three DMins that I use to find the lowest number within three columns. The only problem is when I have an empty column, it returns blank. How can I take into account empty columns?

This is the code I'm using.

```
Private Sub UpdatePriority_Click()

Dim MinGOPri As Variant
Dim MinSRPri As Variant
Dim MinSOPri As Variant

MinGOPri = DMin("[GOPri]", "[Projects]", "Projects.ProjNo = Activity.ProjNo")
MinSRPri = DMin("[StrPri]", "[Projects]", "Projects.ProjNo = Activity.ProjNo")
MinSOPri = DMin("[SOPri]", "[Projects]", "Projects.ProjNo = Activity.ProjNo")

Overal_Priority.Requery

Overal_Priority = IIf(((IIf([MinGOPri] < [MinSRPri], [MinGOPri], [MinSRPri])))
 < [MinSOPri], ((IIf([MinGOPri] < [MinSRPri], [MinGOPri], [MinSRPri]))), [MinSOPri])


End Sub
```

Comment: When you say you take in account what do you mean ?...If it is empty then  you should use nz() function to change empty to your default value (usually 0) ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wish to find the minimum of the three, you could insert a "larger than everything else" value when DMin is Null:

```
' Very large value.
Const Superior As Long = 9999

Dim MinGOPri As Variant
Dim MinSRPri As Variant
Dim MinSOPri As Variant

MinGOPri = Nz(DMin("[GOPri]", "[Projects]", "Projects.ProjNo = Activity.ProjNo"), Superior)
MinSRPri = Nz(DMin("[StrPri]", "[Projects]", "Projects.ProjNo = Activity.ProjNo"), Superior)
MinSOPri = Nz(DMin("[SOPri]", "[Projects]", "Projects.ProjNo = Activity.ProjNo"), Superior)
```

Comment: I just noticed a problem with this where if I have two values in the GOPri column but nothing anywhere else, it sets the priority to 9999.

Comment: Then you have larger values in GOPri than 9999. Increase Superior to be beyond the largest GOPri possible.

Comment: All it does is give me the new number I put in, even though it's much larger than anything in that column.

Comment: Then something else is going on. The code works here. How large is the largest value of GOPri?

Comment: I cleared all the priority columns, so now the highest number is 20. But it still  puts 9999 if only GOPri is filled, and if the lowest number is in GOPri, it takes the lowest from the other two. I don't think it's reading GOPri at all; I checked the spelling and everything is spelled right.

Comment: Double-check your code. I ran a test once more here using the code above, and again the correct result was returned for any set of input values.